What are multiple http "content types" for JSON .?
What are multiple http "content types" for JSON reply.?
Apart from "application/json" content type can we expect any other content types..?
Similarly, do we have any other content types for XML, YAML, & HTML HTTP response.?

Yes, JS has other MIME types other than application/json.
This is a table of some of the MIME types.



File Extension
MIME Type
Description




.aac
audio/aac
AAC audio


.abw
application/x-abiword
AbiWord document


.arc
application/x-freearc
Archive document (multiple files)


.avi
video/x-msvideo
AVI: Audio Video Interleave


.azw
application/vnd.amazon.ebook
Amazon Kindle eBook format


.bin
application/octet-stream
Any kind of binary data


.bmp
image/bmp
Windows OS/2 Bitmap Graphics


.bz
application/x-bzip
BZip archive


.bz2
application/x-bzip2
BZip2 archive


.csh
application/x-csh
C-Shell script


.css
text/css
Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)


.csv
text/csv
Comma-separated values (CSV)


.doc
application/msword
Microsoft Word


.docx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Microsoft Word (OpenXML)


.eot
application/vnd.ms-fontobject
MS Embedded OpenType fonts


.epub
application/epub+zip
Electronic publication (EPUB)


.gz
application/gzip
GZip Compressed Archive


.xml
application/xml is recommended as of RFC 7303 (section 4.1), but text/xml is still used sometimes. You can assign a specific MIME type to a file with .xml extension depending on how its contents are meant to be interpreted. For instance, an Atom feed is application/atom+xml, but application/xml serves as a valid default.
XML file



You can see the full list here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types
But I don't think yaml is included
